# Twitter API v2 でツイートを行う際にPOSTでリクエストが送れない。

Tags: twitter, flutter, oauth, dart

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Flutterで[Twitter API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets) を用いて，ツイートを行いたいと考えています。
Timelineの取得など，GETでのリクエストは以下のように，正しく値を取得できているのですが、POSTでのリクエストは、「発生している問題・エラーメッセージ」に記載のように403が返ってきてしまいます。

ソースコードの処理の流れとしては、

1. 別のファイルで事前に取得しFirebaseに保存している、access_tokenと、access_token_secretを読み込む。
2. oauth1を使ってツイートをするための[エンドポイント](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets)にリクエストをPOST形式で送信。
   という流れです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
flutter: {title: Forbidden, detail: Forbidden, type: about:blank, status: 403}
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oauth1/oauth1.dart' as oauth1;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'root.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/*
void setData(String collection, Map data) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collection).add(data);
}
*/

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  final platform = oauth1.Platform(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    oauth1.SignatureMethods.hmacSha1,
  );
  final clientCredentials = oauth1.ClientCredentials(
    '＜APIキー＞',
    '＜APIシークレットキー＞',
  );
  late final auth = oauth1.Authorization(clientCredentials, platform);
  oauth1.Credentials? tokenCredentials;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    // CallbackURLを"oob"とすることでPINでの認証とできる
    auth.requestTemporaryCredentials('oob').then((res) {
      tokenCredentials = res.credentials;
      // launch() で ログイン用URLを開く
      launch(auth.getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURI(tokenCredentials!.token));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // ログイン後に表示されたPINを入力
              TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // 入力されたPINを元に Access Token を取得
                  final pin = controller.text;
                  final verifier = pin;
                  final res = await auth.requestTokenCredentials(
                    tokenCredentials!,
                    verifier,
                  );
                  print('Access Token: ${res.credentials.token}');
                  print('Access Token Secret: ${res.credentials.tokenSecret}');
                  /*
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test_collection1').add({
                    'access_token': res.credentials.token,
                    'access_token_secret': res.credentials.tokenSecret,
                  });
                   */

                  // 取得した Access Token を使ってAPIにリクエストできる
                  final client = oauth1.Client(
                    platform.signatureMethod,
                    clientCredentials,
                    res.credentials,
                  );
                  /*
                  final apiResponse = await client.get(
                    Uri.parse(
                        'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=1'),
                  );
                  print(apiResponse.body);

                   */

                  final getResponse = await client.get(
                    Uri.https(
                      'api.twitter.com',
                      '/2/tweets',
                      {'text': 'Hello World!!'},
                    ),
                  );

                  final getBody = jsonDecode(getResponse.body.toString());
                  print(getBody);

                  final postResponse = await client.post(
                    Uri.https(
                      'api.twitter.com',
                      '/2/tweets',
                      {'text': 'Hello World!!'},
                    ),
                  );

                  final postBody = jsonDecode(postResponse.body.toString());
                  print(postBody);
                },
                child: Text('認証'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[こちら](https://zenn.dev/luecy1/articles/4e6b59aebd9da15dc51f)に記載されているソースコードのgetをpostに変更したものでもリクエストを送ってみたが、以下のような返答が返ってきた。（OAuth 2.0では認証してくれないらしい。）

その他必要な情報があれば、教えてください。

#### 補足情報

- [Flutter公式ページ（Twitter APIの使い方）](https://www.flutter-study.dev/recipe/twitter)
- Uri.httpsのパラメータの指定方法については、上記の「タイムラインを取得」を参考にしました。
- suzukisさんに教えていただいたパラメータ指定方法で、コードを書いた結果。

```
Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
                  final res = await client.post(
```

- 返ってきたメッセージ

```
flutter: {errors: [{parameters: {ids: []}, message: The `ids` query parameter can not be empty}, {parameters: {text: [Hello World!!]}, message: The query parameter [text] is not one of [ids,expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]}], title: Invalid Request, detail: One or more parameters to your request was invalid., type: https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request}
flutter: {errors: [{parameters: {text: [Hello World!!]}, message: The query parameter [text] is not one of [expansions,tweet.fields,media.fields,poll.fields,place.fields,user.fields]}], title: Invalid Request, detail: One or more parameters to your request was invalid., type: https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージが返ってくるではなく、エラーメッセージそのものを載せたほうが解決につながりやすいです。

まずはFirebase抜きで、oauth系の直接指定で、やってみるのがいいかもしれません。

さらにTwitter APIのドキュメントに載っているようにとりあえずcurlやPOST MANでやってみるのがいいかもしれません。

自分はPOST MAN, curlでTwitter APIのコツがつかめました。

Comment: @zunda さんコメントありがとうございます。
Firebaseを抜きにして、oauth系の直接でリクエストを行ってみました。
その際に帰って来たエラーメッセージは補足情報の中に記載しております。
メッセージの内容を見ると、同じURLにGETリクエストした時の[Twitter lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/introduction)のリクエストと認識されているように思うのですが、postで送れてないのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。post manなども使ってみようと思います。

Comment: 記載している言語に詳しくないため何も言えませんが、簡単なAPIから始めるとわかりやすいです。[isEven](https://isevenapi.xyz)というAPIが非常に簡単です。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>                   final res = await client.post(
>                     Uri.https(
>                       'api.twitter.com',
>                       '/2/tweets',
>                       {'text': 'テスト'},
>                     ),
>                   );
> ```

POSTリクエストのbodyにJSON文字列を指定しないといけないのにクエリパラメータで送ってます。

```
                  final res = await client.post(
                    Uri.https(
                      'api.twitter.com',
                      '/2/tweets',
                    ),
                    "{'text': 'テスト'}"
                  );
```

触ったことないので正しいかどうかはわかりませんがこんな感じになるんじゃないでしょうか。

取り合えずぱっと気づいたのはここですが、もっと手前で引っかかってる可能性もあります。

- どういうリクエストを送らないといけないのか
- 自分のコードが実際どういうリクエストを送っているのか

を確認しながら進めるようにしましょう

Comment: 早速のご返信ありがとうございます。

Uri.httpsのパラメータの指定方法に関しては、Flutterの公式ページ（質問内容に補足）の「タイムラインを取得」を参考にしました。
また、suzukisさんのご提案通りにプログラムを編集した結果も補足情報に載せてあります。

手前で引っかかっている可能性は私も考えたのですが、getでのリクエストがうまく送れていることから、手前で引っかかっている可能性は小さいと判断したのですが、getとpostでは根本的に色々違ってくるのでしょうか？（Twitter API v2 公式ドキュメントを読んだ感じではその辺りの違いがわかりませんでした。）

以上、追加での情報提供を何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: APIを扱うには前提としてHTTPの知識が必要なのでそこから勉強された方がいいとおもいます。

Comment: 承知いたしました。回答ありがとうございます。